# Vault "Failed copying contents" from CRXDE Lite

Tags: java, intellij-idea, filevault, adobe-experience-manager

I am using Java version 1.8, AEM 6.3, Apache Maven 3.6.1, filevault 2.4.40, IntelliJ 2019.2.1 in Manjaro OS.
The problem is after all setup I created a AEM project and tried to push/pull by using IntelliVault plugin from CRXDE lite. And everytime I got this error 
"[ERROR] checkout: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.day.jcr.vault.fs.api.RepositoryFactory is not an ImageIO SPI class".
I also tried push/pull using command lind but I got this same error.

Comment: I seemed to experience this problem as soon as I updated intellij, but can't be sure.

Comment: Java 1.8.0_181, AEM 6.4, Maven 3.5.4, Mac OS, IntelliJ 2019.2.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After this post, I go back to java 1.8 and this works. But I need to OS setup for SSD. Then again install everything but unfortunately, I got this same error.

Comment: See my answer below.  Rolling back to IntelliJ 2019.1.4 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just rolled back to IntelliJ 2019.1.4 and it started working for me. Scroll down a bit to find the 2019.1 section.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html